# Ptrace or waitpid gets stuck in C on macOS

Tags: c, macos, ptrace, waitpid

I'd like to write a mini-debugger with ptrace on OS X.

I want the parent process to make the child process run step by step.

This is what I tried, but the program gets stuck sometimes, it seems to be in an infinite loop or to be frozen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t id = fork();

    if (id < 0)
        return 1;
    else if (id == 0)
    {
        ptrace(PT_TRACE_ME, 0, 0, 0);
        printf("Point 1\n");
        kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
        printf("Point 2\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            int status = 0;
            pid_t retpid = waitpid(id, &status, WUNTRACED);

            if (retpid < 0)
            {
                printf("Waitpid error\n");
                exit(3);
            }

            if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
            {
                int ret = ptrace(PT_STEP, id, (caddr_t)1, 0);
                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    printf("Ptrace error\n");
                    exit(2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Program has terminated\n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compile with `cc bug.c`, run with `while true; do ./a.out; done`, wait 30 seconds and it will freeze.

When it freezes, the last lines are:

```
Point 1
Point 2
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

<sub>Running on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)</sub>

Comment: For me it hung on the 4th iteration, El Capitan.

Comment: Interesting: If I put `sleep(1)` before the `PT_STEP` line, it hangs immediately after the first `Point 1`.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <sys/wait.h>`  to expose the `waitpid()` function.

Comment: the function: `ptrace()` returns a `long int`, not a `int`

Comment: @user3629249: Not so. Your statement ist true for e.g. Linux. For macOS, it is `int`.

Comment: I could avoid the freeze by using `PT_CONTINUE` instead of  `PT_STEP`.